# Android - SharedPreferences - can't get my value

Tags: java, android, sdk, key

I have a very strange problem.

I use key/value pairs to save my application data. And it works fine! I can save and get string-values and boolean-values.

The only type of value, I cant get is **Integer**

Let me describe the situation:

In one activity, I save my key/value pair this way:

```
addElement(getApplicationContext(), "all_tasks", Integer.parseInt(allTasks.getText().toString()));
```

I use this method from my KeyValueStorageHelper.java file:

```
/* Записать новую целочисленную пару */
public static void addElement(Context context, String key, int value) {
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferences = contextWrapper.getSharedPreferences("MentalCalculationSaveData", ContextWrapper.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    sharedPreferences.putInt(key, value);
    sharedPreferences.apply();
}
```

After that, in another activity, I try to do this, and here the strange comes:

```
if (isKeyExists(getApplicationContext(), "all_tasks"))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getInt(getApplicationContext(), "all_tasks"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This code throws an "ResouceNotFound Exception". Okey. But it is strange. If there is no such resource, why my if-else block returns true?

After that I suggested, that maybe this is not an Integer key/value pair.

I tried this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (int)getFloat(getApplicationContext(), "all_tasks"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And it againg throws an exception:

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
```

So what's wrong? How can my value be Integer and throws an exception, when I am trying to get it?

Comment: Where is ResourceNotFoundException is raising ? I think your code doesn't executed inside the if block. Exception is throwing at the condition of if statement

Answer (score 1):

Are you retrieving the shared preferences from the same pref. In your addElement method, you use the "`MentalCalculationSaveData`" one. Make sure you use the same one to retrieve.

Also what is the implementation of your isKeyExists. You can try to use [sharedPreferences's contains method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String)) to check if the key exist or not.

In addition, not sure what is your getInt() method. You can use [sharedPreferences' getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt(java.lang.String,%20int)http://), which you should put the key name as the first parameter, a default value as the second parameter. So you can do something like pref.getInt("all_tasks", 0), if no value exist, the 0 will return.